# Error during template rendering django

Tags: python

This is my code and I receive error on index  page ** {% for post in posts %} Error during template renderingn template /home/elite/Downloads/django/FirstBlog/blog/templates/index.html, error at line 13

**index.html**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang=”en”>
    <head>
    <meta charset=”utf-8”>
    <title>Awesome HTML5 Webpage</title>
    <meta name=”description” content=”An awesome HTML5 page YOU built     from scratch!”>
    <meta name=”author” content=”Udemy”>
    <link rel=”stylesheet” href=”style.css”>
</head>
<body>
   <div class='cointainer'>
   <h1>First Blog</h1>
      {% for post in posts %}  <<<<- This where error I get--
   <h2>{{ post.tittle }}</h2>
   <h3>Posted{{ post.timestamp }} by {{ post.author }}</h3> 
   <p>{{post.bodytext }} </p>
       {% endfor %}


    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**views page**

```
    from django.shortcuts import render

    from blog.models import posts

    def home(request):
        entries = posts.objects.all()[:10]

        return render(request, 'index.html',{'posts' : entries})
```

**This is url page**

```
    from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
    from django.contrib import admin



    urlpatterns = patterns('',
        # Examples:l()

        url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
        url(r'^$', 'blog.views.home', name='home'),


    )
```

Comment: Please see the formatting of your question again. Also, the actual error message/exception seems to be missing from the question?

Comment: I am experiencing the same exact issue. Any solutions for this.